# Which version of apache http client is compatible with java 1.4.2?

Tags: httpclient, java1.4

Somehow I can't find this info

Answer (score 3):

You will find some hints in the release notes of the [download page](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Comment: Looked more carefully again this time and found: Release 4.0 Alpha 3


ALPHA3 release brings another round of API refinements and improvements in 
functionality. As of this release HttpClient requires Java 5 compatible 
runtime environment and takes full advantage of generics and new concurrency primitives. So do all 4.x distibutives require jre 5 and I shoul use 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

### Release 4.5.7

This is a maintenance release that corrects Automatic-Module-Name definitions added in the previous
release and fixes a number of minor defects discovered since 4.5.6.

Please note that as of 4.4, HttpClient requires Java 1.6 or newer.